# RCA tablet: Debugging android app - No compatible targets were found

Tags: android, tablet

I have a RCA 7" tablet and I am trying to debug my android app on it. As it does not provide the drivers by itself , I have downloaded using PDAnet. I have also enabled USB debugging but when I try to run the app it says no compatible devices found.

Does anybody know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Go to SDK manager, and at the bottom in the Extras section there is a generic Google USB driver. Download it, and try to use that as the driver for your tablet... See if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem.

More detailed and Windows instructions are here: http://ryancuda.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-get-working-adb-drivers-for.html

For my Mac, I was able to connect after doing:

1. `android update adb`
2. Find your adb_usb.ini file (`locate adb_usb.ini`, mine was in `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`)
3. Get Vendor ID from running `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`.  Look for your model or serial number.  Mine was "0x2207" for my RCA 7" which showed up as "Fuzhou Rockchip Electronics Co., Ltd."
4. Add the id to the end of the `adb_usb.ini` file `echo "0x2207" >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`
5. `adb kill-server`
6. `adb devices`
7. Accept the computer's key on the prompt on your device